# How to select unique values from different columns in different worksheets using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook in which there are 5 sheets :

1. prize
2. volatility
3. size
4. value
5. growth

These five sheets have a ticker list (stocks name on index) in columns along with the dates . After every three months a new ticker list comes as a result of rebalancing for e.g. PRIZE sheet is having 2 rebalances so 2 ticker lists and SIZE sheet is having 4 rebalances so 4 ticker lists, so all these ticker lists are presented in the five different sheets. I want to make a macro which picks distinct unique values from these lists and paste it in another sheet in one column.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show any code with which you attempted to solve the problem so far? This gives us some reference

Comment: We understand your goal, what is your question??

Comment: i am looping through different sheets, selecting the required columns until last column of specific worksheet is reached and pasting them in a different sheet of the same workbook.Then i used a macro to remove duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  Go to the VB Editor, then Tools, References and select it from there.

After that, paste this code in a proc and see if it gets you over the line.  It'll certainly push your knowledge in a new direction - dictionaries and arrays are amazing things in the right hands and utterly doom-laden in the wrong hands.  You've been warned...!

```
Dim dctUniqueTickers        As Dictionary
Dim dctTickerLocations      As Dictionary
Dim arrCurrentTickerRange   As Variant
Dim arrTickerOutput         As Variant
Dim varSheetNames           As Variant
Dim lngDctCounter           As Long
Dim lngRowCounter           As Long
Dim lngColCounter           As Long
Dim lngAreaCounter          As Long

' Set up the ticker location range(s)
Set dctTickerLocations = New Dictionary
With dctTickerLocations
    .Add "prize", Application.Union(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("prize").Range("A:A"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("prize").Range("C:C"))
    .Add "size", Application.Union(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("size").Range("A:A"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("size").Range("E:E"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("size").Range("F:F"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("size").Range("H:H"))
End With

' Populate the destination dictionary
Set dctUniqueTickers = New Dictionary
For Each varSheetNames In dctTickerLocations.Keys
    ' Looping through the keys (the worksheet names), pick up the associated range(s)
    '  - there may be multiple areas to consider
    For lngAreaCounter = 1 To dctTickerLocations(varSheetNames).Areas.Count
        arrCurrentTickerRange = dctTickerLocations(varSheetNames).Areas(lngAreaCounter)

        For lngRowCounter = LBound(arrCurrentTickerRange, 1) To UBound(arrCurrentTickerRange, 1)
            For lngColCounter = LBound(arrCurrentTickerRange, 2) To UBound(arrCurrentTickerRange, 2)
                If LenB(arrCurrentTickerRange(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter)) > 0 Then
                    If Not dctUniqueTickers.Exists(arrCurrentTickerRange(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter)) Then
                        ' Ticker not found within the dictionary, so add it
                        dctUniqueTickers.Add arrCurrentTickerRange(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter), arrCurrentTickerRange(lngRowCounter, lngColCounter)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next

If dctUniqueTickers.Count > 0 Then
    lngDctCounter = 0

    ' Now output
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputSheet").Range("A1").Value = "Unique tickers"
    For Each arrTickerOutput In dctUniqueTickers.Keys
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputSheet").Range("A2").Offset(lngDctCounter, 0).Value = CStr(arrTickerOutput)

        lngDctCounter = lngDctCounter + 1
    Next
End If
```

By using arrays it's lightning-fast and the extra check for empty cells only improves performance.

Comment: If you want any further explanation of my suggested answer, please ask.  With just a small amount of editing, it should provide your solution.

Comment: these tickers occur after every three months and if i use your code then i will  have to update my ranges(ticker lists) in the code after three months

Comment: So the ticker location changes on each of the sheets every time?  In June it's columns A & B on worksheet "prize" and in July it's E & F?

How do you identify the relevant columns?  You could search through for the header text and make a note of wherever it appear.

Comment: i am looping through different sheets, selecting the required columns until last column of specific worksheet is reached and pasting them in a different sheet of the same workbook.Then i used a macro to remove duplicate values

Comment: > [...] selecting the required columns [...]
How?  What criteria are you employing?  Is it on position (column A, D, etc.) or on the header text ("Ticker_1")?
I have asked specific questions (on two occasions) that you're not answering - indeed, you've just copy/pasted one of your answers.  It's up to you, but I think there's only so much help one can provide.

Comment: IN EACH OF THE SHEETS I AM LOOPING THROUGH COLUMNS(B,E,H,K....) "foR I = 2 TO LASTCOL STEP 3".I COPY PARTICULAR COLUMN AND PASTE IT IN SEPARATE SHEET. THIS IS BEING DONE FOR ALL REQUIRED COLUMNS IN THE SHEETS.

Comment: I'm working on these assumptions that
i) you're not going to have more than 30 columns of tickers on each of the worksheets
ii) the ticker columns aren't going to move around
Given those assumptions, you only have to add lines for each of the columns (B, E, H, K, N, ...) on the worksheets you mention.  I've started you off with my suggestions and if the assumptions are valid, you've got your solution - just ensure that "OutputSheet" or its equivalent exists.

Comment: Alternatively, as long as the columns don't move around, create a named range that contains all of the ticker columns on one sheet (e.g. rngPrize_Tickers, etc.).  That way you'll just have to refer to a single range for each sheet in the code I provided.